# Pandas generate date range of Beginning Month

Tags: python, pandas

What is going on here?
I need to generate  a dataframe with beginning of month dates,,(1-1-2014 To 12-1-2014) fwiw I use the fcast_year variable elsewhere where I need the end of month, hence doing date math

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
fcast_yr=pd.to_datetime('2014-12-31')
x=(fcast_yr + pd.DateOffset(days= -30)) # to set x to 2014-12-01
d=pd.date_range((x +pd.DateOffset(months=-10)), periods=12, freq='MS') #"MS" means start of month!!
print d.values
```

Gives these end of month values....yech!!

```
['2014-01-31T18:00:00.000000000-0600' '2014-02-28T18:00:00.000000000-0600'
 '2014-03-31T19:00:00.000000000-0500' '2014-04-30T19:00:00.000000000-0500'
 '2014-05-31T19:00:00.000000000-0500' '2014-06-30T19:00:00.000000000-0500'
 '2014-07-31T19:00:00.000000000-0500' '2014-08-31T19:00:00.000000000-0500'
 '2014-09-30T19:00:00.000000000-0500' '2014-10-31T19:00:00.000000000-0500'
 '2014-11-30T18:00:00.000000000-0600' '2014-12-31T18:00:00.000000000-0600']
```

Using 13.0 pf Pandas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to coerce the timestamp to the begin month; the frequency will do it (but your answer is correct).

The 'values' are just the way numpy represents dates (they are UTC).

```
In [8]: pd.date_range((Timestamp('20141231') +pd.DateOffset(months=-11)), periods=12, freq='MS')
Out[8]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-02-01, ..., 2015-01-01]
Length: 12, Freq: MS, Timezone: None
```

Comment: mmm.. it works.. I need to use -12 for months.. strange...I think I was fighting something else as well :-) thanks!

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-stamps-vs-time-spans; a datetime subclass in pandas